# Indexing data stored locally through prefs

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a way to index data that has been stored locally using forge.prefs.set()?

For the application I'm working on there is a large amount of data being stored locally and it can be slow to retrieve data using forge.prefs.get().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are using prefs vs say indexDB? prefs are really not ment to store large amounts of data, really its to store some user prefs but large indexes will be slow.

I would highly recommend localforage as it provides a nice shim and is very similar to the localstorage request.

I have similar needs and did at one time try the prefs but they were as mention too slow, I had done this because of the localstorage 5 meg limit, then I switched to indexDB ( localforage ) as it did what I needed and was fast. The way I work it is to dump my localstorage into a runtime variable at app load, this way I can then access it quickly and iterate over the object with a simple loop

If you need more complex operation there are other shims out there but they are more complex then localforage

Comment: We're storing data to allow the app to work while off of the company network and forge.prefs.set() was the option we started with since there wasn't a lot of data at the time. The amount of data we need to store has recently expanded greatly so I'm just looking for efficient ways to store and retrieve that data. I will look into the indexDB solution that you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Yah, I would look at localforage then its simple to use and like I said, its a shim so it will use what ever is supported ( not as important as it used to be but still nice )
http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/

Answer (score 0):

forge.prefs uses [android.content.SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) on Android and iOS respectively.

(See: https://github.com/trigger-corp/trigger.io-prefs/tree/master/inspector)

While there is no upper limit on the amount of data they can persist neither are particularly well-suited for wrangling large amounts of data.

I'd either go with IndexedDB as suggested by proxim0 or possibly even WebSQL.

(WebSQL *is* officially deprecated but it is unlikely that either the iOS or Android web runtimes are likely to drop support any time soon. Also see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated)